# Pre-baking machine image of Elasticsearch 8 with xpack auto security configure shutting me out with TLS errors

Tags: elasticsearch, ssl, elasticsearch-x-pack

I installed Elasticsearch via Packer and Ansible onto a machine image on GCP. I tried running `elasticsearch-reset-password -u elastic` to change the password. I think I'm getting the following error because the installation was done on a different IP address (the IP of the instance Packer launches to bake the machine image vs the IP of the launched instance).

```
WARN  org.elasticsearch.common.ssl.DiagnosticTrustManager - failed to establish trust with server at [10.206.0.10]; the server provided a certificate with subject name [CN=packer-62d379fb-f7c3-ca0f-471a-82185776ac77], fingerprint [eb5436427cb38928b3f16994bfdb8102ac5011be], no keyUsage and extendedKeyUsage [serverAuth]; the session uses cipher suite [TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384] and protocol [TLSv1.3]; the certificate has subject alternative names [IP:10.128.0.20,DNS:localhost,DNS:packer-62d379fb-f7c3-ca0f-471a-82185776ac77,IP:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1,IP:127.0.0.1,IP:fe80:0:0:0:4001:aff:fe80:14]; the certificate is issued by [CN=Elasticsearch security auto-configuration HTTP CA]; the certificate is signed by (subject [CN=Elasticsearch security auto-configuration HTTP CA] fingerprint [63fa2023ea0d36865d838d8d3bd17c5e96f8b684] {trusted issuer}) which is self-issued; the [CN=Elasticsearch security auto-configuration HTTP CA] certificate is trusted in this ssl context ([xpack.security.http.ssl (with trust configuration: Composite-Trust{JDK-trusted-certs,StoreTrustConfig{path=certs/http.p12, password=<non-empty>, type=PKCS12, algorithm=PKIX}})])
java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address 10.206.0.10 found
```

The IP address of the instance I'm launching from the prebaked machine image is `10.206.0.8` instead of `...10`.

This is what I get when I test TLS:

```
curl --cacert /etc/elasticsearch/certs/http_ca.crt -u elastic https://localhost:9200
Enter host password for user 'elastic':
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

I would like to get this ideal path to work but I'm at a loss for what to do. Seems like an opportunity to learn but I'm just scratching my head right now.

Working solutions that I have right now are:

- run ES from Docker and disable xpack when creating the container with an env variable
- pre-bake an install of deb package for es7 (predating the xpack auto config)
- install es8 manually on each node I launch vs pre baking a machine image that is pre-installed and pre-configured

Neither of those are suitable paths forward as they circumvent the platform's new security conventions or throw a wrench in my automated infrastructure goals.

Can I modify the generated certs to work on a newly launched instance from a pre-baked image with a different IP address?

Comment: That's definitely not the recommended path. I'm wondering if [`elasticsearch-reconfigure-node`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/reconfigure-node.html) could help you there, but I haven't tried this specific scenario yet.